# Mac: How to determine what websockets are open?

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket

I am trying to connect to a websocket that a tomcat client has created.
What I see is ws://localhost:8080/cs-webapp/ws but when I try to connect to it, I get a 302 error. Other questions/answers here are not applicable :(

I am using the following command to get a list of open ports on my machine and what I see related to tomcat are:

```
sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
java      localhost:21179 (LISTEN)
java      *:63862 (LISTEN)
java      *:49190 (LISTEN)
java      *:8080 (LISTEN)
java       *:8009 (LISTEN)
java       TCP localhost:8005 (LISTEN)
java        TCP *:58083 (LISTEN)
```

Having the above information, is there a way to determine which is the websocket port and how to connect it?

the code snippets that I have tried are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

var client = new WebSocketClient();

client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
        }
    });
});

//client.connect('ws://localhost:8080/cs-webapp/ws', 'echo-protocol');
client.connect('ws://localhost:63862', 'echo-protocol');
//client.connect('ws://localhost:8080/cs-webapp/ws', 'echo-protocol');
```

Comment: There is no specific system feature that tells you a listening server is listening for a webSocket connection.  From the system point of view, it's just a listening server and there's no indicatation of what protocol it is listening for.  You'd have to connect to it with a webSocket client and see what happened (if the behavior appears to be consistent with a webSocket server or not).

Comment: yes correct. But from the listening ports listed, what would the ws host:port should look like? Any thoughts? depending on what port I try to connect to, I either get socket hungup or 302 error code...

Comment: There is no specific look for a ws host.  A 302 error code means that it at least understands HTTP (which is what all webSocket connections start with).  What is it redirecting you to?  Did you try connecting to all the others?  FYI, it's possible that the 302 is trying to redirect you to TLS, e.g. `wss://localhost:63862`.

Comment: What is `'echo-protocol'` in your `client.connect()` call?